# How to create a pop up input box in VBA for Excel and save the value in a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a pop up box in `VBA`, so I take the input from the user and then I use it in my code.

The only "pop up" box I know at the moment is something like this:

```
MsgBox "This is a pop up box!"
```

It is a bit confusing for someone working only with `C#`.

How can I achieve my objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple Inputbox can be generated as below, this will ask the user to enter something and then display a messagebox with the contents of the variable:

```
Sub test()
    x = InputBox("Enter something", "Title")
    MsgBox x
End Sub
```

Comment: Just to add to this - `InputBox` can be set to accept different inputs by setting the optional `Type` parameter. If you want something more than that you will have to create your own Userform. [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox)

Comment: @Tom: I don't think `InputBox` has the `Type` parameter. I think you will have to use `Application.Inputbox` for that

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works! Tom and Zac thank you for providing extra info for more advanced options ;)

Comment: @Zac thanks for clarifying oversight in my explanation but is what I am referencing

Answer (score 1):

> It is a bit confusing for someone working only with C#.

Indeed it is, since in C# the framework is nicely packaged in clear namespaces.

VBA doesn't have namespaces, but you can make your code not look like it's pulling global functions out of the sky by fully qualifying the global function calls you make.

The global `MsgBox` function, for example, lives in the `VBA.Interaction` module (as does the `InputBox` function); `VBA.Conversion` defines type-conversion functions such as `CLng`; `VBA.DateTime` exposes [almost] everything you need to work with dates and times...

Everything that's *global* is defined somewhere, and you can fully qualify any call to any global function.

You can explore what's defined in what referenced library, by bringing up the *object browser* (F2).

Comment: Thank you for explaining me the difference between C# and VBA. It really helps!